# Conformal mapping of the angle $− \frac{π}{4} <Arg (z) <\frac{π}{2}$ to the right half plane $Im(w)> 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal-maps

Could you help me with the following please:

Find the conformal mapping of the angle $− \frac{π}{4} <Arg (z) <\frac{π}{2}$ to the right half plane $Im(w)> 0$ such that $w (1 - i) = 2, w (i) = -1, w (0) = 0$.

I have seen similar examples, but take $− \frac{π}{2} <Arg (z) <\frac{π}{2}$, I have tried and cannot find a pattern to be able to solve this exercise. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Regards.

Comment: I'm not sure I get how $w(i) = -1$ when we want $\operatorname{Re}(w) > 0$

Comment: An apology, I was wrong, it's 1

Comment: The point $1-i$ lies on the boundary of the domain of $w$, so I am worried if $w(1-i)=2$ is possible.

Comment: You can turn it into a problem on $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \operatorname{Arg} z < \frac{\pi}{2}$ by the substitution $\zeta = (e^{-\frac{i\pi}{8}}z)^{\frac{4}{3}}$, but really I would only consider the rotation at first.

Comment: $\zeta$ tranform $-\frac{\pi}{4}<Arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $-\frac{\pi}{2}<Arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: I have notified of this and they have told me that it is a printing error, which must be $Im (z)> 0$, but the question has arisen if this fixes what they mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s see whether I can get this right:

You want to increase the angle of the wedge from $135°$ to $180°$, so need a $4/3$ power. That is $f_1(z)=z^{4/3}$, which sends $1-i=2^{1/2}e^{-i\pi/4}$ to $2^{2/3}e^{-i\pi/3}$, $0$ to $0$, and $i=e^{i\pi/2}$ to $e^{2i\pi/3}$.

Needs a rotation of $60°$, so multiply by $e^{i\pi/3}$ to get $f_2(z)=e^{i\pi/3}z$. Unfortunately, $f_2\circ f_1$ sends $0$ to $0$ and $i$ to $-1$ all right, but sends
$1-i$ how? Its progress is $1-i\mapsto2^{2/3}e^{-i\pi/3}\mapsto2^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]4$.

So now for $f_3$ all we need is a map of the Upper Half Plane that leaves zero and $-1$ fixed, but moves all other points on the real axis. The general form of such is
$$
f_3(z)=\frac z{cz+1+c}\,,
$$
for real $c>-1$. (In general, a fractional linear transformation of UHP will be given by $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with real coefficients satisfying $ad-bc>0$.)

Well. we need only find $c$ such that $2^{2/3}$ gets sent to $2$, i.s. such that
$$
2=\frac{2^{2/3}}{2^{2/3}c+1+c}\,,
$$
which I solve to get $c=\frac{2^{2/3}-2}{2(2^{2/3}+1)}$, though I may have slipped up in my high-school algebra here. And that does it, setting $w=(f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1)(z)$.

Comment: an apology, referred to as “Its progress is ...”?

Comment: Will you know any software to verify this type of mapping question?

Comment: To your question about verification, @Haus , you know that $f_1$ and $f_2$ get the original domain to the UHP. Only question is about $f_3$. But a fractional-linear transformation of the UHP is determined by what it does to three distinct points. Since this one does what you want, it’s good. All I know on this subject I learned from Ahlfors.